# Inject Func<object, bool> using Unity

Tags: c#, delegates, unity-container

I am experiencing this runtime error when attempting to inject a property using Unity dependency injection:
*System.InvalidOperationException: The property HasNext on type Batch is of type Func'2, and cannot be injected with a value of type Func`2.*

In the Batch class, there is a property defined as:

```
    public Func<object, bool> HasNext { get; set; }
```

I have attempted to set this property with the following code:

```
        _container.RegisterType<Func<ConcurrentQueue<QueryDeal>, bool>>
        (
            new InjectionFactory(c => new Func<ConcurrentQueue<QueryDeal>, bool>(name => !c.Resolve<ConcurrentQueue<QueryDeal>>().IsEmpty))
        );

        _container.RegisterType<IContainer, Batch>(Constants.FeedBatch,
            new InjectionConstructor(
                ...
            ),             
            new InjectionProperty("HasNext", _container.Resolve<Func<ConcurrentQueue<QueryDeal>, bool>>())
        );
```

How do I get this right?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this to work by correcting the type:

```
            new InjectionProperty("HasNext", new Func<object, bool>(_ =>!_container.Resolve<ConcurrentQueue<QueryDeal>>().IsEmpty))
```